# What clasps are used for closing lockets?

Tags: terminology, jewelry

I'm making a wooden locket, and I've got everything together, two halves hinges and everything, but I can't for the life of me find anything about what sort of clasp I should use to close the halves.

Anything I search about jewelry clasps, regardless of whether I include the word "locket", only ever returns info about bracelet and necklace clasps. I'm assuming the word "clasp" is probably incorrect in this context, but I don't know the right term to use; searching with "closure" instead seems to yeild similar results.

Any hints? One thing I should mention is that plain magnets embedded in the halves are a no go for my locket; I'm really looking for a clip or clasp to attach to the side opposite the hinge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a Google search which led me to a Pinterest page called "[Jewelry : cold connections : clasps, bails, lockets, hinges, rivets](https://www.pinterest.com/Nivifer/jewelry-cold-connections-clasps-bails-lockets-hing/?lp=true)." Looking at the pictures led me to some potential search terms and other ideas.

I was looking for a hook and eye type clasp, but there were no pictures of the exact concept I was thinking of--but it would be a riff on this type of clasp: 
[image]

I found this image labeled "latch backing."

[image]

But I would guess that you will have the most luck searching for a "figure eight safety clasp," or "safety clasp."

[image]

Although this is an illustration of a faulty clasp, it does a pretty good job of showing how this type of clasp should work:

[image]

My recommendation is to see if you can find a bead store that offers jewelry classes somewhere near you.  If you take some of these pictures in to show them, they can either help you identify a clasp that will work, or they might be able to point you to someone who does metal work that can make something for you.

Comment: A "figure 8 safety clasp" is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Now if I can just find one that isn't made of silver or gold... definitely don't need anything that fancy or expensive.

Answer (score 4):

I know what you mean about terminology being the key. My quick pop of research shows me that you might want to use "friction clasp" as the search terms, especially as a number of sites which return from this have direct reference to locket construction.

The publisher of [this page](http://createjewelry.gr/blog/single/working_on_the_heart_locket) attempted a friction clasp closure for the locket and was not happy/successful in the result and created an alternative, which may also suit your purposes.

[image: Rejected friction clasp image]

The selected solution is shown below:

[image: selected friction clasp image]

One can see the pin was removed from the first attempt and the hole was not filled in. I believe one can still refer to the solution as a friction clasp, from a mechanical standpoint.

[Another site](https://www.ganoksin.com/article/how-to-make-your-own-locket/) goes into great detail regarding making a locket including the creation of a friction clasp, which appears some distance down the page. It appears that the process results in the rejected design of the first page I've listed, yet I suppose it's personal taste and ability split down the middle:

[image: creation image]